# set increase and decrease button without exceed condition

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a button which triggered for ascending and descending order of for restocking item.

I have tried do some code, it seems normal for ascending order. The problem i'm facing is that, whenever the number is decreasing, the number is not back to normal in **balance** field.

```
private void addStock_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        reStock = Int32.Parse(restock_tb.Text);
        if (reStock >= 0 && reStock < Int32.Parse(qtyAvailable_tb.Text))
        {
            reStock++;
            restock_tb.Text = reStock.ToString();
            qtyBalance = Int32.Parse(qtyAvailable_tb.Text) - Int32.Parse(restock_tb.Text);
            qtyBalance_tb.Text = qtyBalance.ToString();

        }
   }
   catch
   {
       MessageBox.Show("No item selected to be restock!");
   }        
}
```

```
private void minusStock_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        reStock = Int32.Parse(restock_tb.Text);
        if (reStock > 0)
        {
            reStock--;
            restock_tb.Text = reStock.ToString();
            qtyBalance = Int32.Parse(qtyBalance_tb.Text) + Int32.Parse(restock_tb.Text);
            qtyBalance_tb.Text = qtyBalance.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No item selected to be restock!");
    }
}
```

**Expected Output for descending func:**

Available: 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, etc...

restock:   11, 10, 9, 8, 7, ... , 0

**Balance:**  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 11

**Current Output that i get is:**

Available: 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, etc...

restock:   11, 10, 9, 8, 7, ... , 0

**Balance:**  0, 10, 19, 27, 34, ... 55

Answer (score 0):

**CASE CLOSED***

I'm sorry for my careless mistake.

It can be done as below:

```
private void minusStock_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        reStock = Int32.Parse(restock_tb.Text);
        if (reStock > 0)
        {
            reStock--;
            restock_tb.Text = reStock.ToString();
            qtyBalance = Int32.Parse(qtyAvailable_tb.Text) - Int32.Parse(restock_tb.Text);
            qtyBalance_tb.Text = qtyBalance.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No item selected to be restock!");
    }
}
```

**Mistake that I make:**

```
qtyBalance = Int32.Parse(qtyBalance_tb.Text) + Int32.Parse(restock_tb.Text);
                qtyBalance_tb.Text = qtyBalance.ToString();
```

**It should be done like below:**

```
qtyBalance = Int32.Parse(qtyAvailable_tb.Text) - Int32.Parse(restock_tb.Text);
                qtyBalance_tb.Text = qtyBalance.ToString();
```